# Grab Tkinter cursor

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to capture relative mouse motion using Tkinter. I attach a `<Motion>` listener and am able to get mouse movement. However, I would like to be able to "grab" / "lock" the cursor so that it is invisible and cannot leave the window (the same way a game might). My goal would be to get relative mouse movement without the limitation of window borders. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Motion>` only binds to the root window. If you move your mouse outside of root window, it no longer generates the x and y position of your mouse cursor.

For windows, what I can think of is to get the current position of your cursor periodically, and limit its position. The below will try to control the cursor x position within the root window.

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
user = windll.user32

class Position(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_long), ("y", c_long)]

def ctrl_x_pos():
    pt = Position()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    if pt.x < root.winfo_x()+5:
        x = root.winfo_x()+5
        y=pt.y
        user.SetCursorPos(x, y)
    elif pt.x > root.winfo_x()+405:
        x = root.winfo_x()+405
        y = pt.y
        user.SetCursorPos(x, y)
    root.after(5, ctrl_x_pos)

root.after(5,ctrl_x_pos)
root.bind('<Escape>',lambda e: root.destroy())
root.mainloop()
```